# what is the difference between *[]Type and []*Type in go

Tags: go

Let's say we have a struct named `Person` and it's held by a struct named `People`.

```
type Person {
    Name string
    age  int
}

type People {
    City string
    List []*Person //check this out
}

type People2 {
    City string
    List *[]Person //What's the difference?
}
```

1. What's exactly is the meaning of `[]*Person` and `*[]Person`?
2. How can I retrieve the element's value of these slice?

I'm more familiar with C so it's appreciated if you can explain this in C

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `[]*Type` is a slice of pointers to `Type`.
- `*[]Type` is a pointer to a slice of `Type`.

To deference an individual element from a slice of pointers:

```
var x []*Type
y := *x[0]
```

To dereference an individual element from a pointer to a slice:

```
var x *[]Type
y := (*x)[0]
```

And for bonus points, to deference an individual element from a pointer to a slice of pointers:

```
var x *[]*Type
y := *(*x)[0]
```

See [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/720n0lHvJmx).